# Store multiple two dimensional arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I am wondering if for example I have 5 numpy array of 100 by 1, 4 numpy arrays of 100 by 3, 3 numpy arrays of 100 by 5 and 4 arrays of 100 by 6. What is the most efficient way to store all these matrices? I can have just one numpy array for each but this is not efficient. I cannot store them in a 3D array since matrix have different dimensions. Any suggestion on how to efficiently store them ?

Comment: can't you use list for all of them or lists for arrays with the same size ?

Comment: What's not efficient abut 'one array for each'?  `savez` is a good way of storing collections of arrays.  It might be convenient to `stack` the arrays into a (5,100,1), (4,100,3), etc arrays.  `load` might be simpler that way.  `HDF5` via `h5py` is also possible.  Or put everything in a list and use `pickle`.

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming you're speaking of being efficient in storage on disk.*

NumPy has a built in method called [savez](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html#numpy.savez) that you can use to save multiple arrays to disk. If you're worried about file size, there's a minor achievable improvement with [savez_compressed](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez_compressed.html#numpy.savez_compressed)

If you did save the arrays with `pickle` enabled, make sure to include `allow_pickle=True` when attempting to load the saved `.npy` or `.npz` files.

HDF5 is definitely an option but is often used for truly large heterogeneous data collections. From what it appears, you have a handful of homogeneous matrices that can easily be managed using the aforementioned facilities.